# Rails Controller code isn't executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I must be missing something... my views are being rendered, but it appears like code in the controller isn't being executed. I can't find what's wrong.

When I click the login button in `login.html.erb`, the `login_process` method of the PublicController should be called to authenticate the user. That doesn't seem to happen as the view `login_process.html.erb` just displays, which shouldn't be possible.

I've even tried putting a `flash[:notice] = "heyhey"` on the `login_screen` action so it appears on the login form, but that doesn't happen either.

What have I done wrong?
Is it something in the `routes.rb`?

**routes.rb**

```
root :to => "public#index"

get "login",
      :to => "public#login",
      :as => "login_screen"

post "login_process",
      :to => "public#login_process",
      :as => "login_process"

get "logout",
      :to => "public#logout",
      :as => "logout"
```

**public_controller.rb**

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def login_screen
    flash[:notice] = "heyhey"
  end

  def login_process
    authenticated_user = User.authenticate params[:email], params[:password]
    if authenticated_user
      session[:user_id] = authenticated_user.id
      session.countdown_start(1.minute)
      redirect_to :public => :index
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Email/Password incorrect. <a href="#">Receive a new password</a>.'
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
    end
    render :login_screen
  end

  def logout
    session.countdown_abort
    flash[:notice] = "You are now logged out"
    redirect_to :login_screen
  end

  def count
    render :text => session.countdown_count.to_i
  end
end
```

**views/public/login.html.erb**

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag :login_process do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h1>Login</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag :login_process do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**login_process.html.erb**
*I never expect to see this page as the user should be directed elsewhere*

```
<p>login_process.html.erb</p>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

**Update 1:**

> I've modified the `authenticate` action in the User model to be:
>
> ```
> def authenticate(:email, :password)
>   #x = new User
>   #x.id = 123
>   return false #x
> end
> ```
>
> and `login_process` on PublicController to be:
>
> ```
> def login_process
>   if true
>     flash[:notice] = 'boom'
>   else
>     flash[:notice] = 'Email/Password incorrect. <a href="#">Receive a new password</a>.'
>     flash[:color] = "invalid"
>   end
>   redirect_to :login_screen
> end
> ```
>
> Unfortunately though... same issue. The `login_process.html.erb` is
>   displayed with **no** flash notices either.
>
> **Versions:**
>   Ruby 2.0.0p247
>   Rails 4.0.0

Comment: Could you also provide the server log from a request?

Comment: @RobertFalkén sorry for the dumb question... but where would I find or capture that?

Comment: How are you running the app? Locally or somewhere in the clouds? If you run it by typing 'rails server' in the terminal, then you should get the output in your terminal when an http-request is made to the server.

Comment: @RobertFalkén it's on my webhost webfaction.

Comment: @RobertFalkén I probably shouldn't admit this... I've found the problem: I've been using FTP to edit the files, but the connection was lost so changes were never uploaded to the webhost without me realising. Hence, it appeared like code wasn't executing since the files were never really changed. Makes it tough to accept an answer for this one!

Comment: Wow, that's.. something? Probably look into the gem called `capistrano` and deploy your code changes like that. Also just run the rails server locally if you want to make changes to the code and see the results directly. __Don't use FTP for live editing__

Answer (score 2):

The code in your controller is probably executing just fine.

I think the `authenticate` class method on `User` is not giving you the correct result. That's why it doesn't go through the `if authenticated_user` and just renders the `login_process` view. You don't have to call this render command though, it's done for you if you do nothing.

There's a problem with the `login_process` method though. You can't have a render call and a redirect_to be called together, now it can happen in your case, if the user is authenticated. Put the `render :login_screen` in the else case, otherwise you get the `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` error saying: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. [etc.]`
This is what you would get as an error if the user was authenticated.

**Edit:** Running this locally (stubbing `User.authenticate`) on a new Rails project it works. Flash notices appear and everything.
Also: `render :login_screen` is probably `render :login`, no? in login_process?

If nothing works still, what's your: Ruby version, Rails version, put `authenticated_user = false # or true` in login_process to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've tried a few things at you suggest with no luck, see `Update 1` in my question. Thanks for your help. Ruby 2.0.0p247. Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Here it works fine even if I copy your edit over. So... something else might be interfering in the process. You could log the output as suggested in another answer, personally I use the [pry gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/pry) to just hook into the process and be able to see what's what, the context and variable values. That way you can see exactly what's wrong rather than send things to the log over and over again. Using `binding.pry` in your `login_process` method.

Comment: I've found the issue... see comment above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989457/rails-controller-code-isnt-executing?noredirect=1#comment29775551_19989457

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to :public => :index
```

It seems like you are redirecting from login_process to /login_process?public=index, which I don't think is your intention.

If you are meaning to redirect to public#index, try

```
redirect_to root_path
```

(But I can't see that action in your public controller.)

Comment: Thanks - i've fixed this bit. Hasn't resolved the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you call two renders in one action.  You can only render one page per action.

```
 def login_process
    authenticated_user = User.authenticate params[:email], params[:password]
    if authenticated_user
      session[:user_id] = authenticated_user.id
      session.countdown_start(1.minute)
      redirect_to :public => :index
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Email/Password incorrect. <a href="#">Receive a new password</a>.'
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
    end
    render :login_screen
  end
```

The user is authenticated and the redirect_to should bring you to the public/index, however, you call `render :login_screen` after the if statement, so it will execute that portion of the code no matter what and bring you back to the login.

Comment: Thanks this is good to know, but I don't thinks it's getting this far. I've changed the action just use `redirect_to` and it's still not going right.